# Transfer compresses/decompressed + encoded/decoded files between systems in Mule

Tags: compression, base64, sftp, mule

I am using mule sftp endpoint to transfer files between systems. The involved systems have ftp/sftp servers installed and running. But what I want to achieve is to transfer compressed/uncompressed + encoded/decoded files using transformers in Mule. What I have so far is as follows and it does not work:

```
<flow name="flow1">
    <sftp:inbound-endpoint address="sftp://username:password@ip_address:22/path/to/dir1"
        responseTimeout="1000" />
    <string-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="String to Byte Array"/>
    <base64-encoder-transformer /> 
    <gzip-compress-transformer/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" />
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/path/to/Output" />
</flow>

<flow name="flow2">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/path/to/Output" />
    <gzip-compress-transformer/>
    <base64-encoder-transformer /> 
    <string-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="String to Byte Array"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" />
    <sftp:outbound-endpoint address="sftp://username:password@ip_address:22/path/to
    /dir2" responseTimeout="1000" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Quit different actually. The previous question was based on using the Java transformer/component in an automated flow. Though using almost the same code, this has entirely to do with compress/uncompress and encode/decode. Your suggestion yesterday helped me as it worked. But i did not mention anything about gzip + encoding schemes, which is now the focus of this question. I now have the compress/uncompress part working, and also the encode part. But i cannot seem to get the decoding part to work. And that is where i need help now. Thanks.

Comment: Well I can see the difference in configuration, I was mainly attracting your attention to the fact that in StackOverflow, you are supposed to accept the answers that have proven good and that people are reluctant to help users who do not play be the rules.

Comment: I see what you mean. I did accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. My solution was to add the encoding to the encoding/decoding tags as show below:

```
<base64-encoder-transformer encoding="utf8"/> 
...
<base64-decoder-transformer encoding="utf8"/>
```

The also made the encode tag above declared before the following tag:

```
<string-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="String to Byte Array"/>
```